# Creating Content type with multiple sections with sections within them?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I need to create a content type that would allow the user to add text fields, file field and as many X sections (please read on) as he likes.

X section should contain some text fields (easy) and as many Y sections as user likes.

Y should contain some text fields and file field.

The idea is that the user could add X section, such as "We fix bikes" with multiple Y sections within it. Then another X section, such as "We also fix cars" with also multiple Y sections within it. In the end we would have a content type "page" that would have some text, pictures and then any number of X sections in it. Each section would have a number of images with titles in it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Field collection module](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection). It should do what you want.
You add a collection to your node and set it to unlimited, then add your fields to the field collection.